# Getting Django migration error "sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to", but all tables and sequences have the same owner

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to run a migration in a Django project. (Django 3.1, Python 3.9.9) I'm in my virtual environment. I keep getting a puzzling error.

```
 python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, intake, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying intake.0021_auto_20220115_1147...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Sites/client/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to
```

But when I list out my tables and sequences, they all have the same owner.

```
intake=# \dt
                    List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |   Owner   
--------+----------------------------+-------+-----------
 public | auth_group                 | table | dbuser
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | dbuser
 public | auth_permission            | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user                  | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | dbuser
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | dbuser
 public | django_admin_log           | table | dbuser
 public | django_content_type        | table | dbuser
 public | django_migrations          | table | dbuser
 public | django_session             | table | dbuser
 public | intake_byattorney          | table | dbuser
 public | intake_client              | table | dbuser
(12 rows)

intake=# \ds
                         List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   |   Owner   
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+-----------
 public | auth_group_id_seq                 | sequence | dbuser
 public | auth_group_permissions_id_seq     | sequence | dbuser
 public | auth_permission_id_seq            | sequence | dbuser
 public | auth_user_groups_id_seq           | sequence | dbuser
 public | auth_user_id_seq                  | sequence | dbuser
 public | auth_user_user_permissions_id_seq | sequence | dbuser
 public | django_admin_log_id_seq           | sequence | dbuser
 public | django_content_type_id_seq        | sequence | dbuser
 public | django_migrations_id_seq          | sequence | dbuser
 public | intake_byattorney_id_seq          | sequence | dbuser
 public | intake_client_id_seq              | sequence | dbuser
(11 rows)
```

Why might this be? Do I need to change the ownership of the tables and sequences to something else, like `postgres`?

This is happening locally and on my production machine.

Here is the content of the migration in question:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('intake', '0020_alter_client_status'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='byattorney',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='client',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='client',
            name='status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('1__intake', 'Stage 1: Needs initial contact'), ('2__attorney-review', 'Stage 2: Needs attorney contact'), ('3__evaluation', 'Stage 3: Evaluation - Accept/Reject'), ('4__final-disposition', 'Stage 4: Final Disposition'), ('5__client-accepted', 'Client Accepted'), ('6__client-rejected', 'Client Rejected')], max_length=20),
        ),
    ]
```

Here is the output of `python manage.py sqlmigrate intake 0021':

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate intake 0021
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field id on byattorney
--
SET CONSTRAINTS "intake_client_by_attorney_id_680583a2_fk" IMMEDIATE; ALTER TABLE "intake_client" DROP CONSTRAINT "intake_client_by_attorney_id_680583a2_fk";
ALTER TABLE "intake_byattorney" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE integer USING "id"::integer;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS "intake_byattorney_id_seq" CASCADE;
CREATE SEQUENCE "intake_byattorney_id_seq";
ALTER TABLE "intake_byattorney" ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT nextval('"intake_byattorney_id_seq"');
SELECT setval('"intake_byattorney_id_seq"', MAX("id")) FROM "intake_byattorney";
ALTER SEQUENCE "intake_byattorney_id_seq" OWNED BY "intake_byattorney"."id";
ALTER TABLE "intake_client" ALTER COLUMN "by_attorney_id" TYPE integer USING "by_attorney_id"::integer;
ALTER TABLE "intake_client" ADD CONSTRAINT "intake_client_by_attorney_id_680583a2_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("by_attorney_id") REFERENCES "intake_byattorney" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
--
-- Alter field id on client
--
ALTER TABLE "intake_client" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE integer USING "id"::integer;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS "intake_client_id_seq" CASCADE;
CREATE SEQUENCE "intake_client_id_seq";
ALTER TABLE "intake_client" ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT nextval('"intake_client_id_seq"');
SELECT setval('"intake_client_id_seq"', MAX("id")) FROM "intake_client";
ALTER SEQUENCE "intake_client_id_seq" OWNED BY "intake_client"."id";
--
-- Alter field status on client
--
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the migration file `intake.0021_auto_20220115_1147`?

Comment: @IainShelvington: thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to include the migration's contents.

Comment: Looks like the migration is altering a couple of your `id` fields, is this expected, what did you change? Can you run [`python manage.py sqlmigrate intake 0021`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) and add the output to the question, will give an idea of the actual SQL Django is trying to run. Have you maybe changed your DB settings recently?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that one. I added it to the question. I do think it's strange, those  first two migration changes; I don't see a corresponding code change to explain them. The third one reflects what I was trying to do, which is make the statuses orderable by an arbitrary order instead of alphabetically.

Is it possible to edit or skip a migration, or am I just asking for trouble?

Comment: You could remove those two AlterField operations for the `id` fields so the migration is just the change you actually want to make and apply it. Then create a separate migration for the `id` changes and run `python manage.py migrate intake --fake` to mark the new migration as applied but not actually run it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, IainShelvington. Migrating the migration as `--fake` did stop the error from happening and allow me to make changes and perform the migration as planned.
I'm still puzzled by the nature of the error message, but this was a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly the same problem with my project after `makemigrations` on id as `BigAutoField`. It turns out that this SQL error is caused by a former issue.
If you run a `./manage.py showmigrations` it should mention that your 0021 intake migration is not done.

```
intake
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20220214_1030
 [X] ...
 [ ] intake.0021_auto_20220115_1147
```

However, `django_migrations` table in your DB should list this `intake.0021` migration. Which means that it is already applied.

```sql
SELECT name FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'intake' AND starts_with(name, '0021');
```

But, the DB name listed might be slightly different than the existing file name: `0021_auto_20220115_1147` (run @ 11:47). eg in DB: `0021_auto_20220115_1056` (run @ 10:56). This might be due to a `makemigrations` done on a different server than the one currently used (dev).

Change the file name according to what you have in `django_migrations` in the DB and run `manage.py migrate` again and it should work.

The error is caused by the ALTER SEQUENCE statement.

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE "intake_byattorney_id_seq" OWNED BY "intake_byattorney"."id";
ALTER SEQUENCE "intake_client_id_seq" OWNED BY "intake_client"."id";
```

With postgres, `AutoField` primary key is managed by a sequence. Why django is not using a `ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name as bigint` syntax instead of a DROP - CREATE? I don't know but the `CREATE SEQUENCE` done by `manage.py` assign a **`postgres` OWNER** to the sequence and that's the source of the issue because the table.column to which the sequence is associated has **`dbuser` OWNER**.

Therefore the execution of `ALTER SEQUENCE OWNED BY` statement willing to associate the newly created sequence to the appropriate table.column with a different OWNER triggers the `sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to` error.